# How to test that a powershell function has a cmdletbinding attribute

Tags: powershell

I'm trying out writing test-driven PowerShell code using Pester. Is there a way to test if a function has a certain CmdletBinding attribute, e.g. SupportsShouldProcess and ConfirmImpact:

```
function Remove-Something {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess, ConfirmImpact = 'High')]
    param ()
...
```

Is that kind of metadata available from the result of e.g. Get-Command?

```
$functionUnderTest = Get-Command Remove-Something
# How to test if $functionUnderTest has SupportsShouldProcesses defined?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of a mouthful, but you can try something like this to get the attributes:

```
function Invoke-MyFunction {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess, ConfirmImpact = 'High')]
    param ()
}

(get-command Invoke-MyFunction).ScriptBlock.Ast.Body.ParamBlock.Attributes

#PositionalArguments : {}
#NamedArguments      : {SupportsShouldProcess, ConfirmImpact}
#TypeName            : CmdletBinding
#Extent              : [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess, ConfirmImpact = 'High')]
#Parent              : param ()
```

and then you'll need to filter that to find an attribute called "CmdletBinding" and check the arguments specified on it.

```
$command       = Get-Command -Name "Invoke-MyFunction";
$attributes    = $command.ScriptBlock.Ast.Body.ParamBlock.Attributes;

$cmdletBinding         = $attributes | where-object { $_.TypeName.FullName -eq "CmdletBinding" };
$supportsShouldProcess = $cmdletBinding.NamedArguments | where-object { $_.ArgumentName -eq "SupportsShouldProcess" };
$confirmImpact         = $cmdletBinding.NamedArguments | where-object { $_.ArgumentName -eq "ConfirmImpact" };
```

From there you can check whatever other parts of the definition you want to confirm exist...

Note - error handling left as an exercise for the reader :-)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is interested in Test-driven development with PowerShell using Pester. Based on [mclayton's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton) answer above, I have created a set of test functions and published them in a PowerShell module called TDDUtils.

It has functions like Test-TDDCmdletBinding and Test-TDDOutputType that allows you to write Pester tests like:

```
function My-Command
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    ...
}

It "Should be an advanced function" {
    $c = Get-Command -Name My-Command
    Test-TDDCmdletBinding $c | Should -BeTrue
}
```

And

```
function My-Command
{
    [OutputType([Bool])]
    ...
}

It "Should have Output type Bool" {
    $c = Get-Command -Name My-Command
    Test-TDDOutputType $c -TypeName 'Bool' | Should -BeTrue
}
```

Install it from a PowerShell administrator shell:

```
Install-Module TDDUtils
```

https://github.com/hansEricG/TDDUtils for complete source and more information.

Comment: Also, I've created the PowerShell module TDDSeams that enables you to mock the built in ShouldProcess and ShouldContinue features. For more information, see https://github.com/hansEricG/TDDSeams.